# Creating a sample size in business objects

Tags: sql, random, reporting-services, business-objects

Is it possible to make a random sample size of 10% or a fixed amount in business objects (web intelligence) without using filters that would create a bias?

Answer (score 1):

In **BI4**, yes.

In the query panel, click Query Properties:

[image]

then check off *Sample Result Set* and set the appropriate count:
[image]

It works by wrapping the original query in a "SELECT *", ordered by random and limited.  For Oracle, this would look like:

```
SELECT  *  FROM
  (select blah,blah,blah from foo)
ORDER BY
  dbms_random.value)
WHERE  ROWNUM  <=  500
```

Comment: Hi Joe, I have two queries running they're both from different universes. Query 1 doesn't allow me to do "sample result set", while query 2 allows me to make that edit, I still get the full population of data.

Comment: Your first query may be using a RDBMS that doesn't support random numbers. For the second one, what does the SQL look like?

Comment: SELECT
  cog_view.CRM_Individual_IM.Social_Security_Nbr,
  cog_view.CRM_Individual_IM.Length_Of_Mbrshp
FROM
  cog_view.CRM_Individual_IM,
  cog_view.IND_Model
WHERE
  ( cog_view.CRM_Individual_IM.Ind_Id=cog_view.IND_Model.IND_Id  )
  AND  
  (
   cog_view.IND_Model.Period_End_Dt  >=  {d '2014-05-31'}
   AND
   cog_view.IND_Model.IND_Mbr_Flag_Ind  =  1
   AND
   cog_view.IND_Model.IND_Mtg_Ind  =  1
  )

I think it only selects a random sample size of that one field where the two universes were merged.

Comment: I don't see the `random` order in that SQL; this is after you set "Sample Result Set"? It can only produce a random sample from the **final** result; as if you pulled the complete result into a report and took the sample from there -- it's not going to take a sample from data that doesn't meet the query conditions.

Comment: Sorry I sent you the pre-sample run
SELECT
  cog_view.CRM_Individual_IM.Social_Security_Nbr,
  cog_view.CRM_Individual_IM.Length_Of_Mbrshp
FROM
  cog_view.CRM_Individual_IM,
  cog_view.IND_Model
WHERE
  ( cog_view.CRM_Individual_IM.Ind_Id=cog_view.IND_Model.IND_Id  )
  AND  
  (
   cog_view.IND_Model.Period_End_Dt  >=  {d '2014-05-31'}
   AND
   cog_view.IND_Model.IND_Mbr_Flag_Ind  =  1
   AND
   cog_view.IND_Model.IND_Mtg_Ind  =  1
  )
SAMPLE  253

So the "Membership length" comes out to a count of 199, I think that's because theirs some blanks numbers in the data.